# Use Custom Setting URL in Outbound Message

Tags: customsetting, workflowoutboundmessage

Can I direct the url on an Outbound Message to a url in Custom Setting?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be no. Outbound messaging via workflow is a specific form of web services set up to an end point that's been white listed. The url the feed goes to is controlled by the WSDL for the service and the endpoint that's been whitelisted.